# git push is successful and able to see compare and pull in git hub but not able to accept it or merge it

Tags: git

[image: git hub]
[image: commands]
[image]

git push is successful and able to see compare and pull in git hub but not able to accept it or merge it
could someone help me with this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: the new GitHub repositories are created with the default branch named `main`, not `master`.

By pushing your local `master`, you are pushing an unrelated history (no common ancestor commit), which means there can be no comparison between two different branches based on two entirely different histories ([`pbchandra/test` commits `main`](https://github.com/pbchandra/test/commits/main) vs. [`pbchandra/test` commits `master`](https://github.com/pbchandra/test/commits/master)).

So it is best to change your local repository default branch to main:

```
cd /path/to/local/repo
git branch -m master main
git fetch
git rebase origin/main
git push --force -u origin main
```

Comment: Receiving below error now when i trying to use above commands

To https://github.com/pbchandra/test.git
 ! [rejected]        main -> main (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/pbchandra/test.git'

Comment: @Bhuvan Try the push with `--force` in that case. (just when you are deaming with your main branch)